# R: Strange regex matching using quantifier "+"?

Tags: r, regex

Hi suppose I have a term like this.

```
temp = "Big Satchel - Bird - turquoise"
```

I want to remove everything after the last "-"

so I first test this with this command it works as expected.

```
stringi::stri_replace_last(temp, regex = '-...', '')
[1] "Big Satchel - Bird rquoise"
```

however this does not,

```
> stringi::stri_replace_last(temp, regex = '-.+$', '')
[1] "Big Satchel "
> stringi::stri_replace_last(temp, regex = '-.+?$', '')
[1] "Big Satchel "
```

So why is it that when I don't have the quantifier it found and removed the last matched but fails otherwise?  What I ultimately want to do is have it print.

```
Charming Satchel - Bird
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[^-]+` to match one or more characters that are not a `-`.  The `.` is a metacharacter that can match any character.  So, in the OP's post, it matched the first `-`, followed by one or more all other characters

```
stringi::stri_replace_last(temp, regex = '\\s*-[^-]+$', '')
#[1] "Big Satchel - Bird"
```

---

With the current syntax, we can wrap with another `stri_replace` to get the expected

```
stringi::stri_replace(stringi::stri_replace_last(temp, 
     regex = '\\s*-[^-]+$', ''), regex = '\\w+', 'Charming')
#[1] "Charming Satchel - Bird"
```

---

Or use a single `stri_replace`

```
stringi::stri_replace(temp, regex = "^\\w+(\\s+.*)\\s+-[^-]+$",  "Charming$1")
#[1] "Charming Satchel - Bird"
```

Comment: great, this work, but for my own understanding why does adding the "^" make it work? Does that not indicate it has to be in the beginning of the string? Would be great if you can help explain the various steps? thank you so much!

Comment: @Ahdee If it matches the first `-`, then that condition is not met i.e. there is still one more `-` before the end of the string when we use `[^-]+`.  So, it makes sure to always match the last `-`

Comment: strangely I find that this works as well! ```stringi::stri_replace_last(temp, regex = '- [a-z| A-Z]+$', '')```

Comment: @Ahdee It is because your string have only upper/lower case and space characters.  If it also have other numbers etc, you may have to specify them as well.  The use of `[^-]` make sure that anything other than `-`

Comment: thanks man, I really appreciated it.  You solved a lot of my R questions that would otherwise taken me a painful amount of time to figure out.  many thanks.